# Different tile images on different OS versions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any way to specify different tile images for different Windows Phone OS versions.

For example, for WP8 i need to have a non-transparent tile image, and for WP8.1 I need to have a transparent tile image, but this needs to be available without first time opening the app in case the user wants to pin the app to the start screen immediately after install.

Comment: Anyway if the user is having an 8.1 device, he/she could install 8 or 8.1 apps. It would be an issue if the user has an 8 OS.

Comment: How does the Threepointer app manage their tile settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the only way to accomplish that is to submit two separate files to the Windows Phone Store.

In the first file you define the non-transparent tile image and target that XAP file only for WP8.0 devices.

Then you would generate a second XAP where you have your transparent tiles. You submit that second XAP to the store and target only WP8.1 devices for that XAP.